ModSecurity + Fail2Ban ban client IP sending post to Servlet
I am using:

Ubuntu 24.04
Plesk Obsidian 18.0.62
Apache/2.4.59
Tomcat/10.1.16
tomcat-connectors-1.2.49
libapache2-mod-jk
ModSecurity
Fail2ban
Free ModSecurity Rules from Comodo

And I have a servlet on worker1.
In Plesk, ModSecurity is set to "On" and uses Free ModSecurity Rules from Comodo.
IP Address Banning (Fail2Ban) intrusion detection is "On".
When I make 5 (successful) post from client to the servlet, the client IP is banned during the time interval set in Fail2Ban.
Here is the modsec_audit.log report:
--ffd6be58-A--
[30/Jun/2024:09:37:02.722882 +0000] ZoEnPjdhHHdmdP54dSpN12AAFQ ***banned client IP*** 49290 127.0.0.1 7081
--ffd6be58-B--
POST /tomcat_app/Debate/url_a_servlet_general HTTP/1.0
Host: www.mywebsite.com
X-Real-IP: ***banned client IP***
X-Accel-Internal: /internal-nginx-static-location
Connection: close
Content-Length: 181
sec-ch-ua: "Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"
x-gwt-module-base: https://www.mywebsite.com/tomcat_app/Debate/
x-gwt-permutation: A7F24557812452238ACA3ACDA68F4D27
content-type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
accept: */*
origin: https://www.mywebsite.com
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: https://www.mywebsite.com/index-booking.html
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,ar-ES;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7,en-ES;q=0.6,en;q=0.5
priority: u=1, i
cookie: c=cookie-text

--ffd6be58-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 200
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Length: 45
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Expires: Sun, 14 Jul 2024 09:37:02 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

--ffd6be58-H--
Message: Warning. Match of "pmFromFile userdata_wl_content_type" against "TX:0" required. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/10_HTTP_HTTP.conf"] [line "17"] [id "210710"] [rev "5"] [msg "COMODO WAF: Request content type is not allowed by policy. Please update file userdata_wl_content_type.||www.mywebsite.com|F|2"] [data "TX:0=text/x-gwt-rpc"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "HTTP"]
Message: Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:incoming_points. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/20_Outgoing_FiltersEnd.conf"] [line "35"] [id "214930"] [rev "1"] [msg "COMODO WAF: Inbound Points Exceeded|Total Incoming Points: 5|www.mywebsite.com|F|2"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "FiltersEnd"]
Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 275] [level 3] [client ***banned client IP***] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "pmFromFile userdata_wl_content_type" against "TX:0" required. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/10_HTTP_HTTP.conf"] [line "17"] [id "210710"] [rev "5"] [msg "COMODO WAF: Request content type is not allowed by policy. Please update file userdata_wl_content_type.||www.mywebsite.com|F|2"] [data "TX:0=text/x-gwt-rpc"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "HTTP"] [hostname "www.mywebsite.com"] [uri "/tomcat_app/Debate/url_a_servlet_general"] [unique_id "ZoEnPjdhHHdmdP54dSpN12AAFQ"]
Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 275] [level 3] [client ***banned client IP***] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator GE matched 5 at TX:incoming_points. [file "/etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/comodo_free/20_Outgoing_FiltersEnd.conf"] [line "35"] [id "214930"] [rev "1"] [msg "COMODO WAF: Inbound Points Exceeded|Total Incoming Points: 5|www.mywebsite.com|F|2"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "FiltersEnd"] [hostname "www.mywebsite.com"] [uri "/tomcat_app/Debate/url_a_servlet_general"] [unique_id "ZoEnPjdhHHdmdP54dSpN12AAFQ"]
Apache-Handler: jakarta-servlet
Stopwatch: 1719740222713534 9429 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1719740222713534 9429; combined=2313, p1=292, p2=1896, p3=29, p4=23, p5=73, sr=63, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); CWAF_Apache.
Server: Apache
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"

--ffd6be58-Z--

I want to go on using my servlet (from any IP) without significantly reducing the level of security of the server.
I think that I should add a custom directive in Plesk->tools&settings->Web Application Firewall->configuration, to accept application/json. Am I right?
I can read under the text box: "Input a ModSecurity directive here. It will override the previously specified directives (rule sets, specific rules, the predefined set of values, and so on)."
How to write this rule?

It is probably not a json problem but text/x-gwt-rpc. I think that the solution is:
1- Edit the file userdata_wl_content_type
2- Add the line "text/x-gwt-rpc" at the end 
3- Restart apache (e.g. systemctl restart apache2.service)

It works. I am not an expert so I am not 100% sure that this does not open a vulnerability. But I think that is is fine and this answer can help others with a similar issue.
Edit: this does not work as the file is periodically updated.

CRS dev-on-duty here. I don't know the Comodo WAF rule set. But I know the OWASP CRS rule set.
In CRS you can configure your allowed content-types in the crs-setup.conf: https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/main/crs-setup.conf.example#L506 (uncomment and add your content-type).
Maybe this helps.
If you want to know more about WAF tuning and the OWASP CRS, see here:
https://coreruleset.org/docs/concepts/false_positives_tuning/

Thank you very much for the suggestion. But to configure this through the crs-setup file, I would first have to change whole set of rules from Comodo to OWASP (more secure). I will have a try and I may do that if I see that OWASP rules do not interfere with other functions.

I don't know Comodo WAF rules, maybe you'll find something similar to this crs-setup.conf file in Comodo as well. Good luck!
